# Android: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-inflate

My application crashes at setContentView function in DetailActivity and gives Inflating class fragment Error

```
09-13 13:14:13.197 26270-26270/com.example.cs.movista.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cs.movista.app, PID: 26270
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cs.movista.app/com.example.cs.movista.app.DetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
        at com.example.cs.movista.app.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5976)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:297)
        at com.example.cs.movista.app.DetailActivityFragment.onCreateView(DetailActivityFragment.java:81)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
        at com.example.cs.movista.app.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:17) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5976) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

DetailActivity.java

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString("image", getIntent().getStringExtra("image"));
            arguments.putString("title", getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
            arguments.putString("date", getIntent().getStringExtra("date"));
            arguments.putString("overview", getIntent().getStringExtra("overview"));
            arguments.putString("ID", getIntent().getStringExtra("ID"));
            arguments.putFloat("vote", getIntent().getFloatExtra("vote",0));

            DetailActivityFragment fragment = new DetailActivityFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.TwoPaneView, fragment)
                .commit();
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_detial.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/TwoPaneView"
    tools:context="com.example.cs.movista.app.DetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_detail" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_detail.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.example.cs.movista.app.DetailActivityFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
```

fragment_detail.xml:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.cs.movista.app.DetailActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  >

        <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:id="@+id/detail_image"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/original_title"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detail_image"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/overview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/original_title"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/release_date"
            android:layout_below="@+id/overview"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/vote"
            android:layout_below="@+id/release_date"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add to my favorites"
            android:id="@+id/Favorite"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/detail_image"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/original_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/original_title" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:id="@+id/TrailerListView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vote"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/ReviewListView"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TrailerListView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you add the error as well from logcat?

Comment: Please remove the irrelevant code (leave only the important classes or parts of them), and post the whole error from the logcat.

Comment: Done. I posted the Logcat error

Comment: You still need to load it: `ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_image);
Picasso.with(this).load("<image url>").into(imageView);`